# Why Microsoft Word keeps auto-correcting "dB" to "Db" even after I added one entry instructing Word to correct "Db" into "dB"?

Tags: microsoft-word

This is quite annoying to someone who needs to key in dozens of "dB" every day, isn't it? It seems there is an underlying design which persistently change "dB" to "Db" regardless the Autocorrection setting.

Comment: related: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook_com/forum/all/outlook-changes-db-to-db-and-turns-on-my-cap-lock/85c39070-0301-4f1d-b45e-938cc65cf0e0

Answer (score 2):

The most logical reason for this to fail is because you have more than one languages installed for spelling and you fixed it for your native language, but not the default language.

Basically, when you type a sentence in a new document, until you press enter, word will not try to set the language because there are too few words. After you press enter it will make a guess and sets the langauge. If you set this correction on one dictionary, it will not automatically apply to another dictionary, and if you normally have a different dictionary set after word finds the language, it will work after the language has been determined, but not before.

Comment: Thanks. The issue appears to me not caused by Language setting. I normally stick to English when using Word. And naturally, I wouldn't expect Word to still respect the Autocorrection setting if I switch to other languages. Are you saying you don't have the same issue when typing in "dB"?

Answer (score 0):

As shown in the picture, you can uncheck these two option boxes in **Word-Options-Proofing-AutoCorrect**.

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately what I need is to keep the autocorrection feature while avoid changing dB to Db.